# Getting values depending of condition

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I´m  very new in asp.net. For some people my question disturb community.

I have a query that retrieves data from a stored procedure like this:

```
result = context.GetEmployeeTraining(idTraining, 
                                     idArea, 
                                     idDepartment, 
                                     type ? "(1),(2)" : "(3)").ToList();
```

and I have this query to retrieve a list of branches:

```
IGenericRepository<Employee> employee = new GenericRepository<Employee>();
var branchList = employee.GetList(x => x.BranchOfficeId == userId).ToList();
```

How can I filter the result of the first query to get only items that are in the `branchList`?

First I tried to get it from where condition like:

```
 result = context.GetEmployeeTraining(idTraining, 
                                      idArea, 
                                      idDepartment, 
                                      type ? "(1),(2)" : "(3)")
                 .Where(x => x.BranchOfficeId == userId).ToList();
```

But it only get one value instead of  list like my `branchList` do now

```
 var branchList = employee.GetList(x => x.BranchOfficeId == userId).ToList();
```

`GetEmployeeTraining` Stored Procedure:

```
public virtual ObjectResult<EmployeeTraining> GetEmployeeTraining(Nullable<int> idTraining, 
    Nullable<int> idArea, 
    Nullable<int> idDepartment, 
    string type)
```

Area query

```
IGenericRepository<Area> area = new GenericRepository<Area>();
 var areaList = area.GetList(x => x.Id == idArea).Select(x => x.Id);

                    result = context.GetEmployeeTraining(idTraining, idArea, idDepartment, type ? "(1),(2)" : "(3)")
                   .Where(x => branchList.Any(b => b.BranchOfficeId == x.BranchOfficeId) && areaList.Contains(x.Id))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Also it is not really clear what you are doing: the parameter is called `branchList` but the table is `employee`?

Comment: Yes, I updated my question @GiladGreen

Comment: I thuink you asked for method is an stored procedure, I upload it @GiladGreen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use `.Any`:

```
var branchList = employee.GetList(x => x.BranchOfficeId == userId);

var result = context.GetEmployeeTraining(idTraining, 
                                         idArea, 
                                         idDepartment, 
                                         type ? "(1),(2)" : "(3)")
                    .Where(x => branchList.Any(b => b.BranchOfficeId == x.BranchOfficeId))
                    .ToList();
```

Another option if you chnage the query of the `branchList` is to use `Contains`:

```
var branchList = employee.GetList(x => x.BranchOfficeId == userId)
                         .Select(x => x.BranchOfficeId);

var result = context.GetEmployeeTraining(idTraining, 
                                         idArea, 
                                         idDepartment, 
                                         type ? "(1),(2)" : "(3)")
                    .Where(x => branchList.Contains(x.BranchOfficeId))
                    .ToList();
```

As Haitham mentioned in the comments, and the reason why I asked seeing the `GetEmployeeTraining` function, adding these `Where` conditions after the stored procedure was called means that the filtering happens in memory. If instead of a stored procedure you would do these queries in linq (and having `GetEmployeeTraining` as an extention method for instance) then adding the extra `Where` would filter results in database.

Comment: Applying the `Where` condition after calling the procedure will filter the data in memory not on SQL level

Comment: @HaithamShaddad - correct. That is why initially I wanted to see definition of `GetEmployeeTraining`. Updated answer

Comment: @GiladGreen are you there?

Comment: @Dawin - yap here

Comment: I want to filter by area too, but it didnt get registers, I post new query in 1 minute

Comment: There is in my question @GiladGreen

Answer (score 0):

You should change your procedure to accept a table-type parameter and pass the branch list to it, as EF will not generate a dynamic SQL for you in this case and any filtering after calling procedure will be in memory.

So, if your procedure returns 500 employees, and the results wanted for the selected branches was 50, then you wasted your resources for retrieving an extra 450 records